# How can i solve my drag-drop outlet problem?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11, outlet

i am trying to make an outlet from main.storyboard to ViewController.swift, but when i drag an outlet from my view in storyboard, xcode isn't showing any place where to put an outlet.
How can i solve this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to add your class file name like below [image]

Answer (score 0):

Delete your item from main storybord and drag same position in same view controller.may be its working for u,remeber don't use special character.

Answer (score 0):

[image]On your chosen storyboard, select 'identity inspector' and define your viewcontroll to the 'custom class' section

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the class set for the storyboard. Now you should be able to open the view controller class via assistant(see image below). [image]